# Why doesn't Wang's attack work on SHA-1?

Tags: hash, cryptanalysis, collision-resistance, sha-1, attack

[Wang's (et al) differential attack](http://merlot.usc.edu/csac-f06/papers/Wang05a.pdf) works on MD5, MD4, RIPEMD and HAVAL.

Why doesn't it work on SHA-1?

Comment: The website https://sites.google.com/site/itstheshappening/ has the details of another attack on SHA-1 from Marc Stevens (CWI, the Netherlands), Pierre Karpman (Inria, France and NTU Singapore) and Thomas Peyrin (NTU Singapore).

Answer (score 6):

The message expansion step in SHA-1. The compression functions for MD4,MD5, RIPEMD and I think HAVAL only re-arrange and re-use words in the message block.

SHA-1 will expand the message from 16 words to 80 words using a rotation and XOR operation. The additional 64 words are a function of every word of the message block.

Because of this additional dependence on previous words in the block, Wang's attack will not work.